# insert into MySQL from an array with multi-type elements PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert data from an array.The problem is when i **implode** the array , int values convert to String.Is there a way to keep each array element type?

```
$insData=array (
    0 => string 'sds' (length=3)
    1 => string 'dsds' (length=4)
    2 => string '1251' (length=4)
    3 => string 'jklj' (length=4)
    4 => string 'jklj' (length=4)
    5 => int 0
    6 => string 'jkkj' (length=4)
    7 => int 0
    8 => int 0
    9 => int 0
    10 => int 0
    11 => int 0
    12 => int 0
    13 => int 0
    14 => int 0
    15 => int 0
    16 => int 0
    17 => int 0
    18 => int 0
    19 => int 0
    20 => int 0
    21 => int 0
    22 => int 0
    23 => int 0
    24 => int 0
    25 => string '2017-06-28 10:06:24')

$escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string',array_values($insData));
$values  = implode(", ", $insData);
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO `myTable` VALUES ($values)";
var_dump($sql1);
=> INSERT INTO `myTable` VALUES (sds, dsds, 1251, jklj, jklj, 0, jkkj, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2017-06-28)
try {
    $stmt1 = $bdd->prepare($sql1, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR, PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
    $stmt1->execute();
    $row1 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT);
    $stmt1 = null;
  }
  catch (PDOException $e){
    print $e->getMessage();
  }
```

I'm getting a MySQl error .Is there a way to get this :

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` VALUES ('sds', 'dsds', 1251, 'jklj', 'jklj', 0, 'jkkj', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '2017-06-28 10:06:24')
```

Comment: Is there an error message? If so, what does it say?

Comment: In your query missing table `fields`.

Comment: error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sds' in 'field list'

Comment: You would be better off using something like PDO, there you use bind variables, this means that the values will retain their original types anyway. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019826/php-generate-dynamic-pdo-insert may help with that.

Comment: Show your full `INSERT` query

Comment: where is your column ?

Comment: i dont think colums are necessery , i have used another insert query without it and it worked ...

Comment: this is why prepared statements are important

Comment: Do you have auto-increment field in your db ?

Comment: @Maha, Try my answer...

Comment: @MinarMnr  i don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the link I posted, using PDO prepared statements and linking the values when you execute the statement...

```
$valueString = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($insData), '?'));

$stmt = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ({$valueString})");
$stmt->execute(array_values($insData));
```

Edit:
I think the difficulties you were having is that you wanted to retain the type whilst ensuring safety.  This would involve putting quotes round only the string fields in your query and not the numeric ones.

You could have done a loop through the array and used `is_string($value)` and then only quoted these fields.  But this adds a lot of complication and extra processing.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted you, but here's a +1 for you :)

Comment: @Maha don't forget to mark this answer as the [_accepted answer_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: though, i would love to have an explanation why PDO query didn't work ..

Answer (score 0):

```
$integerIDs = array_map('intval', explode(',', $string));
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: which $string ?

Comment: @Frits My bad try this link to get complete info - https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_map.asp

Comment: @Maha $string is the string you want to convert into array. In your case its $insData

Comment: No no no, you misunderstand me. Don't give me a link, add the relevant text in your answer. Your answer should be completely understandable before I click on the link you supply (which should be supplied in your answer, not the comments). The link should be merely to reference the source of your answer. Try adding the basic explanation to your answer via the edit function - this will greatly improve the answer and your chances of an upvote :)