# I got a working array but my code isn't working to display each row of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I am using a working function that perfectly displays the contents of a csv file.

```
function csv2array( $filename, $delimiter )
{
// read the CSV lines into a numerically indexed array
$all_lines = @file($filename);

if( !$all_lines ) 
{
    return FALSE;
}
$csv = array_map( function( &$line ) use ( $delimiter ) 
{
    return str_getcsv( $line, $delimiter );
}, $all_lines );

// use the first row's values as keys for all other rows
array_walk( $csv, function( &$a ) use ( $csv ) 
{
    $a = array_combine( $csv[0], $a );
});

array_shift( $csv ); // remove column header row

return $csv;
}

$items = csv2array( 'filetest.csv', ';' );

//print_r( $items );




echo '<pre>';
var_dump( $items );
echo '</pre>';
```

The var_dump output is perfect and displays:

```
  array(40) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Jurisdiction"]=>
    string(2) "AL"
    [" Total Distance(mi.)"]=>
    string(7) "1730.68"
    [" Off Road(mi.)"]=>
    string(4) "2.63"
    [" Toll Road(mi.)"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Jurisdiction"]=>
    string(2) "AR"
    [" Total Distance(mi.)"]=>
    string(6) "826.27"
    [" Off Road(mi.)"]=>
    string(4) "1.35"
    [" Toll Road(mi.)"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Jurisdiction"]=>
    string(2) "DE"
    [" Total Distance(mi.)"]=>
    string(5) "49.11"
    [" Off Road(mi.)"]=>
    string(4) "0.34"
    [" Toll Road(mi.)"]=>
    string(4) "6.57"
  }
```

I am trying to display the values of those $rows which sounds super easy but I am getting empty values and searched the internet and cannot find the right way to do it.  Here is my code:

```
foreach($items as $row) 
{ 
    echo $row[0]. " ".$row[1]." ".$row[2]."TESTTEST<br>";  
}
```

but I only get the TESTTEST results but the total number of times it displays TESTTEST is correct but the values are empty so what am I missing? I searched this site and others and they seem easy but mine isn't working. Thanks.

Comment: Well... You made the array associative, so 0, 1 and 2 does not exist anymore, you need the Jurisdiction, off road and that to output it.

Comment: echo $row['Jurisdiction']; // ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is nest the loop or implode it.

Nesting:

```
foreach($items as $row) 
{ 
    foreach($row as $val){
        echo $val . " ";
     }
    echo "TESTTEST<br>";  
}
```

Or implode:

```
foreach($items as $row) 
{ 
    echo implode(" ", $row);
    echo "TESTTEST<br>";  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a numerical index for the data as you've just added the column name as the index.

But you can just [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the data anyway...

```
foreach($items as $row) 
{ 
    echo implode(" ", $row)."TESTTEST<br>";  
}
```

Comment: Thanks that kinda works it now displays:                 
AL 1730.68 2.63 0TESTTEST
AR 826.27 1.35 0 TESTTEST My goal is to get them sorted so I can add them to a database

Comment: Your not going to add them with an echo are you?

Comment: no I will assign a variable to them. The code I posted was a test so I can see that each value was being displayed properly

Comment: But what do you mean by sorting? Are you sure you included the full question and problem in the question?

Comment: If all works well I plan to use something like insert into DATABASE (blah, blah2,) values (10, 20);

Comment: If you are going to add the `$items` array to a database, why do you need to sort them.  If you need to sort them, then sort the array and not the output.  But as @Andreas points out, this isn't part of the question and adding it to the question may alter the answers.

Comment: OK I am very sorry for the confusion.  I thought my example would be enough for me to figure the rest out on my own.  I basically want each value separated so I can use an SQL query to insert each value into a database cell instead of having just one output for each row.  The answers provided so far are correct though.

Comment: Perhaps having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019826/php-generate-dynamic-pdo-insert may give you some ideas how to do that with your original array.

Comment: yes that is something more to what I am thinking about thanks bud

Comment: Sweet Frank posted what I was looking for along with your great help Andeas I used: echo $row['Jurisdiction'] . $row[' Total Distance(mi.)']; and it works thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone I got it the way I want and can expand from here on out. I was looking for this code:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($items as $row) 
{ 

    echo $row['Jurisdiction'] . $row[' Total Distance(mi.)'] . "TESTTEST<br>";

    $i++;
} 

echo 'total: ' . $i;
```

I will be sure to trim out the space on the names.

Comment: Not sure if it is - if you are building the file dynamically from the input file - why are you then hardcoding the names of the columns?

Comment: It's just my easy way of testing it by comparing it to the original csv file.  I am sure you guys know a way better way of doing it but this is the way I debug and will write the query separately after I add code to strip out harmful code.

Comment: From the other answer I pointed you to `$keys = array_keys($row)` gives you the names of the columns and then `$row[$keys[0]]`